# How can I get my ng-grid to re-sort itself?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have some data displayed in an ng-grid.

Some of this data is displayed nearly immediately after the page loads; other data is slower and we stitch it in once it's received.

In doing this, sorting can break if the grid is set to sort data that isn't there when the first half of the data is rendered in the grid.

Is there a nice way to tell the grid to re-sort itself and preserve multiple columns as well as sort directions once all of the data has been received?

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 43},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{ field: "name", },
                     { field: "age" },
                     { field: "state" }],
        sortInfo: {
            fields: [ 'age', 'state' ],
            directions: [ 'asc', 'desc' ]
        }
    };

    var lateData = [
        { name: 'Moroni', state: 'NY' },
        { name: 'Tiancum', state: 'CA' },
        { name: 'Jacob', state: 'PA' },
        { name: 'Nephi', state: 'AK' },
        { name: 'Enos', state: 'MO' }
    ];

    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.myData = _.merge($scope.myData, lateData);
        $scope.$digest();
    }, 3000);
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller = "MyCtrl">
        <div ng-grid="gridOptions" class="gridStyle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/akukucka/4vrQq/

Comment: Can you please add a bit of code perhaps?

Comment: What is the specific action that triggers more data to be loaded into the grid?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you wanted:

```
$scope.resort= function(){
  $scope.gridOptions.sortBy('age');
};
```

[Plunker is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4fBjDwGIy5rIQSimVe4I?p=preview)

Since I don't have any of your code you have to find a place where/when to do the sorting for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I've updated the original question with additional details and a fiddle.